# Merge two data frame in R wide format

Tags: r

I´ve to merge two data frames in R. I had melted my two original datasets into two data frame in the wide format:

The first: Price data frame

| Date | Stock | Value | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | A | 1 | PRICE |
| 2021-01-01 | B | 3 | PRICE |
| 2021-01-01 | C | 4 | PRICE |
| 2021-01-02 | A | 1 | PRICE |
| 2021-01-02 | B | 3 | PRICE |
| 2021-01-02 | C | 4 | PRICE |

The second: Volume data frame

| Date | Stock | Value | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | A | 1 | VOLUME |
| 2021-01-01 | B | 3 | VOLUME |
| 2021-01-01 | C | 4 | VOLUME |
| 2021-01-02 | A | 1 | VOLUME |
| 2021-01-02 | B | 3 | VOLUME |
| 2021-01-02 | C | 4 | VOLUME |

I tried to merge both data frames in one with this code but couldn't obtain my desired data frame.

```
desire<- merge(Dataframe1, Dataframe2, by = c("Date", "type"))
or
desire <- melt(rbind(Dataframe1, Dataframe2), id.vars = c("Date", "type"), value.name = "value")
```

That is my desired data frame:

| Date | Stock | Value | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | A | 1 | PRICE |
| 2021-01-01 | B | 3 | PRICE |
| 2021-01-01 | C | 4 | PRICE |
| 2021-01-01 | A | 0.5 | VOLUME |
| 2021-01-01 | B | 0.2 | VOLUME |
| 2021-01-01 | C | 0.1 | VOLUME |
| 2021-01-02 | A | 1 | PRICE |
| 2021-01-02 | B | 3 | PRICE |
| 2021-01-02 | C | 4 | PRICE |
| 2021-01-02 | A | 0.5 | VOLUME |
| 2021-01-02 | B | 0.2 | VOLUME |
| 2021-01-02 | C | 0.1 | VOLUME |

Comment: `rbind(DataFrame1, DataFrame2)`? It's not clear where your `0.5` values come from, but it looks to be just a row-concatenation, no merge or melt. Am I missing something?

Comment: Nor does it look "wide"... both data frames start as long, and the result is long.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here rather than tables of your data. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 0):

you try:

desire <- union(Dataframe1,Dataframe2)

I didn't understand the decimal values ​​in table desire

Comment: Thanks. I tried with that but dont´t work for me so I tried with union_all and that work it. The decimal values are a typo.